# Class non-type template parameter partial specialization

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

I was playing around with some c++20 features using gcc 9.0.1. It seems like there is support for class non-type template parameters. But I run into a problem that template partial specialization isn't used when selecting the template.

Following example is a test case which I came up after figuring out the root cause in my more complex code.

```cpp
// g++ -std=c++2a -c test.cc -o test.o

#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct Integer {

    constexpr Integer() : val{} {}
    constexpr Integer(T v) : val{v} {}

    constexpr bool operator<(Integer o) const { return val < o.val; }

    template<typename O, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<O>>>
    constexpr bool operator<(O o) const { return val < o; }

    constexpr bool operator==(Integer o) const { return val == o.val; }

private:
    T val;
};


template<auto val, typename = void>
struct test {
    static constexpr bool is_specialized = false;
    static constexpr auto value = val;
};

template<auto val>
struct test<val, std::enable_if_t<val < 64>> {
    static constexpr bool is_specialized = true;
    static constexpr auto value = val;
};


constexpr int i5 = 5;
constexpr int i70 = 70;
constexpr unsigned long s5 = 5;
constexpr unsigned long s70 = 70;
using IT = Integer<int>;
constexpr Integer<int> o5 = 5;
constexpr Integer<int> o70 = 70;

static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(test<i5>::value),decltype(i5)>);
static_assert(test<i5>::value == i5);
static_assert(test<i5>::is_specialized);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(test<i70>::value),decltype(i70)>);
static_assert(test<i70>::value == i70);
static_assert(!test<i70>::is_specialized);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(test<s5>::value),decltype(s5)>);
static_assert(test<s5>::value == s5);
static_assert(test<s5>::is_specialized);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(test<s70>::value),decltype(s70)>);
static_assert(test<s70>::value == s70);
static_assert(!test<s70>::is_specialized);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(test<o5>::value),decltype(o5)>);
static_assert(test<o5>::value == o5);
// GCC 9.0.1: error: static assertion failed
// This basically mean object template parameters work but specialization isn't
// used like I would expect.
static_assert(test<o5>::is_specialized);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(test<o70>::value),decltype(o70)>);
static_assert(test<o70>::value == o70);
static_assert(!test<o70>::is_specialized);
```

I tried to find online anything which would indicate if my expectations are correct or not. To me it seems like at least without specialization class non-type parameter works the way I would expect but specialization isn't selected.

One suspect is missing support for three-way comparison (operator<=>). Proposal seems to require defaulted operator. As operator support is missing it might make the class non-type template parameter support only partial even tough [status page](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx2a) claims support.

I couldn't test this with clang as my latest version doesn't yet support this feature. I don't know if latest sources already implement support.

Is this just a bug in the preliminary implementation?

Is there a rule preventing this case from working?

Is there a simple modification which would make the code to select specialization like I expect?

Relevant standard paper: [Class Types in Non-Type Template Parameters](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0732r2.pdf)

Comment: It’s `operator==(…)=default` that is required by the latest draft, but I don’t think GCC enforces anything yet.

Comment: Thanks. Default comparison operators are still linked to three-way comparison if I understand correctly. At least for GCC feature implementation so they are also missing still. I guess there is some kind of preliminary equality check but no enforcement for correct operator.

Comment: Each *operator* can call the other automatically in some cases, but a defaulted `operator==` _function_ will never use `<=>` directly to avoid exponential runtime for nested container-like things.  GCC may very well have implemented the behavior of that defaulted operator without the class having asked for it.

Comment: This changed before C++20 was finalized: now no operator is relevant to class-type non-type template parameters.  That probably doesn’t explain this bug, though.